# ActiveRecord child can't access itself after after_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the current code

```
class NotifyBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_instance
  after_save :update_notifications

  def update_notifications
    notifier = NotificationHandler::Notifier.new
    notifier.check_and_update_status(self.user_instance.id)
  end
end
```

Here's the controller create:

```
class NotificationBarController< ApplicationController
   before_action :set_user_instance, only: %i[show edit update destroy remove_user_instance add_user_instance]
 ...
  def create
    @notify_bar = NotifyBar.new(notify_bar_params)
    @notify_bar.user_instance= @user_instance

     respond_to do |format|
      if @notify_bar.save
        format.html { redirect_to client_notify_bar_url(@user_instance), notice: 'Notification Bar was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @notify_bar }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @notify_bar.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
  private
    def set_user_instance
      @user_instance = NotifyBar.find(params[:instance_id])
    end
end
```

However, when the after_save fires, I get this:

> NoMethodError in NotifyBarController#create
>   undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

How do I reliably pass the id of the belongs_to variable?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `user` instead of `userIntance`? Or, `user_instance`?

Comment: Yep. It's a custom class, another one based of ActiveRecord. Same with NotificationHandler. The NotifyBar is actually made from the userInstance, so I know the userInstance exists and is linked to the NotifyBar.

Comment: Oh yea, standard convention. Okay, I've corrected that. Still doesn't work though, same error.

Comment: Just to make it more clear, can you also update your question to reflect the after_save method as update_notifications instead of update_me...and provide the create method of the NotifyBarController create action (which is what the errors suggests)

Comment: Alright, had to hunt a bit, but here it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, NotifyBar was being called by an outside class, a 'helper' class, that I was unaware of. It was calling update_notifications (same as if after_save had been called), but when the class was newly created and had yet to be saved. It was then erroring out because pre-save, the classes variables aren't always accessible.

So, I guess the takeaway is if an ActiveRecord class has it's variables mysteriously 'dissappearing', it may be they haven't been created in the first place because ActiveRecord has yet to save. (And a second takeaway, if you're going to use helper classes, it might be helpful to have those helper classes also put a note commented into the class they're helping that those helper functions are trying to help.)

Answer (score 1):

You've not shown enough code to know for sure, but looks like `@user_instance` is `nil` on this line: `@notify_bar.user_instance= @user_instance` so you're setting that association to `nil` in your model.

If not so, show how you're setting that in your controller?

#### Update

New code shows a callback that's not being called on the `create` action, so `@user_instance` is not being set.  Even if it was set, it would be set to a `NotifyBar` instance, so that wouldn't match the `belongs_to :user_instance` in your `NotifyBar` model anyway.

Comment: Added an Update to my answer.